# Get front matter data of specific pages into table in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

I want to get some information from the front matter (`{{ page.title }}` and `{{ page.status }}`) for some of my site pages into a table on my index page.

How should I do this?

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Page title</td> <td>Page status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ page-name-1.title }}</td><td>{{ page-status-1.status }}</td>         
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ page-name-2.title }}</td><td>{{ page-status-2.status }}</td>         
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a specific page from the [`site.pages`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables) collection with the Liquid filter [`where`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#where) of Jekyll.

Given I have a page *foo.md* with this front matter:

```
---
title: foo
status: bar
---
```

Then this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Page title</td> 
    <td>Page status</td>
  </tr>
  {% assign page_info = site.pages | where: 'name', 'foo.md' %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ page_info[0].title }}</td>
    <td>{{ page_info[0].status }}</td>         
  </tr>
</table>
```

Will render as

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Page title</td> 
    <td>Page status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>         
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Just repeat it for any page that have an interest for you:

```html
{% assign pages_info = 'foo.md,index.md' | split: ',' %}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Page title</td> 
    <td>Page status</td>
  </tr>
  {% for page_name in pages_info %}
    {% assign page_info = site.pages | where: 'name', page_name %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ page_info[0].title }}</td>
      <td>{{ page_info[0].status }}</td>         
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```